# how do you emit to specific user in a specific room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hey guys please i need help emiting data to a specific user in a specific room using socket.io, am using redis to store the id's of the admin who created the group, but how do i get the userid from redis and emit to them in their room

**my code**

```
const users = {} 
const admins = {}


io.on('connection',socket =>{

socket.on('create-class',(address,userID)=>{
  client.hmset(`${userID}`, `id`, `${userID}`); 
})


socket.on('join-class',(classId,palsid)=>{
  
      socket.join(classId)
      client.hgetall(`${palsid}`, function(err, object) {
        if(err)throw err
          
          if(object !==null){
            admins[socket.id] = object.id 
          }
         
           socket.to(classId).broadcast.emit('user-connected',palsid)
       
    });                    
     
      

      //on disconnection
      socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
          socket.to(classId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnect',palsid)
      })

   
  })
```

Comment: Can you add a little bit more of your code ? Emiting to one specific socket should be fairly easy and independed from which room it is in.

Comment: Again, if you want to emit something to one specific socket, it does not matter in which room it is. 

What is it you try to emit to the one user ? And when ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information OP offers I can only give a few pointers.

First you need to get the socket (specific user), ideally by its id.

```js
const socket = io.sockets.connected[socketid];
```

Then you just emit to this socket

```js
socket.emit("message", "hello world");
```

This should send a message to one specific socket (user), independent from which room it is in. This still leaves the question on where to get the socketid, but to answer that we need more information about your code/setup/app. Usually socket ids are kept in some sort of store/database or memory.

#### Keep reference to the socket id

Now, the socket id is something temporary. Whenever a socket connects, it gets a different socket id. How would one identify one specific user to any socket if the socket id is temporary ?

**A : Store a reference to the socket id using something non-temporary**

When a user is connecting to the websocket server, there is a chance he/she does that along with a unique user id. If you have a database of users, they all have an unique identifier (usually). Keep this identifier together with the socketid when the socket is connecting and you will have reference to the socket at any later point in time using the unique user identifier. There are different ways on how to pass a long something like a user id while the socket is connecting : you can use a query token for example :

```js
// client side
const ioClient = require('socket.io-client');
ioClient(url + '/?token=aaaabbbbccccdddd');

// server side
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  const userid = socket.handshake.query.token; // aaaabbbbccccdddd
  inMemoryStore.sockets[userid] = socket.id;
    
});
```

**B : Use non-temporary id as socket id**

There is also the option to set your own custom socketid per socket. Like this you could use the user id or any other non-temporary identifier as socket id directly. Something like this :

```js
// server side
io.engine.generateId = (req) => {
  return req.query.token;
}
```

Comment: Well am trying to create a webrtc app and I want a scenario where the admin can get the stream of all the users who are connected in that group but all the users get only the admin stream like a one to many peer connection

Comment: Now my problem is how do I get the I'd from redis, store it and then emit to that admin in a specific room incase there is more than one room, because if there is more than one room means there are more than one admin stored in redis

Comment: Sorry it's still not 100% clear to me what it is you are trying to achieve. I seems it's more of a "structural" problem. If you have the id of any socket, you can just emit only to that socket using the code above. I guess you store all socket ids (when they connect) under a reference id (that never changes, like user id or similiar) - so you never loose reference to the socket id. Sry at this point I am not able to help you more.

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe I got the right direction

Comment: @princerandy you care for showing what you did in the end ? Or did my answer help you ? ( if that's the case please accept it as the correct answer )

Answer (score 0):

first of all i didn't know if you refresh a page the socket id changes so i made a button at the frontend that sends a signal to the server, identifying the user as admin the server takes the socket id saves to redis, when any user joins that particular room the server jus fetch that admin id and send to the user connecting, allowing them to share their stream. then using io.to(socketID).emit('user-connected', palsid); to emit back to just the admin socket. so any user who gets connected to that room the stream is sent to just the admin and not everyone else in the room making it a one to many video conference

**my front end code**

```
//for button
<Button onClick={this.setAdmin}>send stream</Button>

the function
setAdmin=()=>{
        console.log(socket.id)
            socket.emit('create-class',this.props.match.id,socket.id)
        }
```

**my backend code**

```
io.on('connection',socket =>{

socket.on('create-class',(address,socketID)=>{
  //save to redis so all client can connect to this socket
  client.set("adminsocket",socketID,(err)=>{
    if(err)throw err;
  })
  
})
socket.on('join-class',async(classId,palsid)=>{
      socket.join(classId)
//Fetch the socket.id from redis
client.get("adminsocket",(err,socketID)=>{
  if(err) throw err
    io.to(socketID).emit('user-connected', palsid);
})
   
      //on disconnection
      socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
          socket.to(classId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnect',palsid)
      })

   
  })
```